# gradient keeps switching between cells in collection view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, gradient

I have a gradient background for my collection view cell and each gradient is different depending on what tag the cell is (e.g Christmas is a purple gradient, birthday is a green gradient) however when scrolling through the collection view, the gradients keep on changing cells. is there a way to fix this from happening?

this is the code I use to set the gradient to the background view. it is in `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.mainView.setGradientBackground(colours: self.getColourFromTag(tag: self.lists[indexPath.item].tag))
```

`.setGradientBackground` is an extension of UIView which just sets a gradient to the background. shown here:

```
func setGradientBackground(colours: [CGColor]) {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = colours
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

I use the method below to get what colours are in the gradient

```
func getColourFromTag(tag: String) -> [CGColor] {

    if tag == "Christmas" {

        return [Colours.gradients.festive.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.festive.end.cgColor]

    }else if tag == "Birthday" {

        return [Colours.gradients.lime.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.lime.end.cgColor]

    }else if tag == "Valentines Day" {

        return [Colours.gradients.strawberry.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.strawberry.end.cgColor]

    }else if tag == "Charity" {

        return [Colours.gradients.blueberry.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.blueberry.end.cgColor]

    }else if tag == "Event" {

        return [Colours.gradients.fire.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.fire.end.cgColor]

    }else{
        return [Colours.gradients.midnight.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.midnight.end.cgColor]
    }
}
```

I have tried appending each [colour] into an array, then placing that into the `.setGradientBackground` at the `indexPath.item` like so:

`var colours = [[CGColor]]()`

```
colours[indexPath.item] = self.getColourFromTag(tag: self.lists[indexPath.item].tag)
cell.mainView.setGradientBackground(colours: colours[indexPath.item])
```

however, this does not work since it is out of range. Does anyone have a solution? thank you.

Comment: And what does `setGradientBackground()`?

Comment: I have edited the question to show that code :)

Comment: Cells are reused and you do each time `layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)`. So with the reuse, if the cell had a previous layer, it will be: layer at 0: new gradient, layer at 1: previous layer, etc. Remove the previous layer if found as a `CAGradientLayer`

Comment: thanks for the reply, how would I do this exactly? (remove the layer if found)

Comment: `layer.sublayers.filter(where: {$0 as? CAGradient}).forEach{$0.removeFromSuperlayer}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading your code in `setGradientBackground()`, you always init a new `CAGradientLayer` and insert it at the lowest position in your cell. Every time `setGradientBackground()` gets called again, the new gradient layer will be positioned below all other gradients you already inserted.

Try to get a already existing `CAGradientLayer` from sublayers and set the new colors.

```
    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    if let sublayers = layer.sublayers {
        for sublayer in sublayers {
            if let gLayer = sublayer as? CAGradientLayer {
                gradientLayer = gLayer
                break
            }
        }
    }
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = colours
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

**EDIT**

This is a more swift like version (Swift 4.2) using `compactMap()` for getting the first existing gradient layer in `layer.sublayers`:

```
if let existingLayer = (layer.sublayers?.compactMap { $0 as? CAGradientLayer })?.first {
    gradientLayer = existingLayer
}
```

Comment: I used this for a different reason. I used it to check if the layer is a subLayer and it works well, thanks

Comment: thanks a lot for this amazing solution! :D